# In this situation, Which is correct の or から?

Tags: grammar

1. 私は東京の田中です。
2. 私は東京から田中です。

I am want to say Hello, I'm Tanaka and I'm from Tokyo, but I am not sure which is correct. I feel like 2 is the right choice but am not sure.

So which is correct and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) 私は東京の田中です。

2) 私は東京から田中です。

1) is grammatical and natural-sounding except for the pronoun part.  「東京の田中です。」 would sound much better to us native speakers.

2) is not grammatical so it makes little sense as is.  To leave the 「から」, you need to add a 「の」 because 田中 is a noun.  「東京からの田中です。」 is the grammatical sentence.

Between 「東京の田中です。」 and 「東京からの田中です。」, it is difficult to choose which one is better without more context, but the former would certainly be a little more versatile because there is an equal amount of emphasis placed on the name and the city one came from.  The latter could sound like the speaker is placing more emphasis on the place s/he came from.

If you are willing to add a few more words, 「東京から[参]{まい}りました田中です。」 or  「東京から参りました田中と[申]{もう}します。」 would be an excellent choice in case you are over 18-20.  「参る」 is the humble version of 「来る」, and 「申す」 for 「いう」.

Comment: I'd like to know why you specifically say 'in case you are over 18-20'. Wouldn't someone younger be able to use those forms?